# Convert charset in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, character-encoding

I have a question about converting charset from inside mysql query.

I have a 2 databases. One for the website (joomla), the other for forum (IPB).
I am doing query from inside joomla, which by default have "SET NAMES UTF8".
I want to query a table inside the forum databases. A table called "ibf_topics". This table has latin1 encoding.

I do the following to select anything from the not-utf8 table.

```
//convert connection to handle latin1.
$query = "SET NAMES latin1";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();

$query = "select id, title from other_database.ibf_topics";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
//read result into an array.

//return connection to handle UTF8.
$query = "SET NAMES UTF8";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

After that, when I want to use the selected tile, I use the following:

```
echo iconv("CP1256", "UTF-8", $topic['title'])
```

The question is, is there anyway to avoid all this hassle?
For now, I can't change forum database to UTF8 and I can't change joomla database to latin1 :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could open 2 database connections, 1 to joomla and one to IPB. you'll be using more resources, but it will make your code easier to read, and you can do all the configuration (charset etc) in the db setup. this will also make it easier to migrate later, in case your situation changes - you won't need to go through your code removing all the `SET NAMES`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SET NAMES UTF8";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();

$query = "select id, title from other_database.ibf_topics";
$db->setQuery($query);
$db->query();
```

Comment: sorry? I didn't get it.
Could you please explain more? What is the difference between this and my code?

Comment: I got your answer, but this don't work.. I should change names to latin1 before selecting from "other_database.ibf_topics"; This table contains non-english letters which is corrupted If connection is in UTF8.

Comment: @Yosif well for the properly set up database you shouldn't. But as it seems you have improper charset set for the ibf table (latin1 for the 1256 data), there is no simple way anyway. So, you can leave your code as is. Because your hassle not in this code but in the improper database setup.

Answer (score 0):

/*
  you can set charset after database connection
*/

header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

/* 
after connection
*/

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");

/*
or
*/

mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");

/*
or
*/

mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_general_ci'");